# Rails method for concatenate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is it possible to concatenate Array `['a', 'b', 'c']` to String `"a, b and c"` ?
But `['a', 'b']` should transform to `"a and b"`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails provides a [`to_sentence`](http://apidock.com/rails/Array/to_sentence) helper:

```
> ['a', 'b'].to_sentence
 => "a and b" 
> ['a', 'b', 'c'].to_sentence
 => "a, b, and c"
```

If you want `a, b and c` rather than `a, b, and c` you can change the `last_word_connector`:

```
> ['a', 'b', 'c'].to_sentence(last_word_connector: " and ")
 => "a, b and c"
```

Comment: nice one. Had no idea about this

Answer (score 2):

```
a = %w{ a b }
str = a[0..-3].each_with_object("") do |item, res|
 res << "#{item}, "
 res
end
str << "#{a[-2]} and  #{a[-1]}"
p str
```

Answer (score 1):

```
a = ['a', 'b', 'c']
result = a[0...-1].join ', '
result += " and #{a[-1]}" if a.length > 1
result # => a, b and C

a = ['a', 'b']
result = a[0...-1].join ', '
result += " and #{a[-1]}" if a.length > 1
result # => a and b
```